# How could I build a continuous parallax scroll/table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am looking to build a continuous parallax scroll view for iOS that would act as a tableView. What I want to recreate is very similar to the scrolling shown on [this page](http://moto360.motorola.com/). I have seen a lot of 'double view' parallax views, but none that are continuous in function.

I know this isn't a direct question, but I could really use some help getting set in the right direction for making this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd suggest watching some of the WWDC videos about scroll views. I'd prob use a scroll view directly to control it instead of a table view.

Comment: I am working with a tableview right now by using the footer/header views. Since the footer/headers 'stick' to the top/bottom I can set it up in a way that provides a similar look/feel. I mostly attempted it by using the footer view, but it's not exactly how I would like it. What kind of approach would you take with a scroll view to get that effect? Would you use some kind of container for each photo object?

Comment: Will put a rough answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways that you could approach this.

I'd probably not use a table view but I think from first look that I'd use a `UIScrollView` and 2 `UIImageViews` and an `NSArray` of images (depending on how many images there are).

The 2 image views will be placed one on top of the other on the main `view` then on top of them both will be the scroll view with nothing in it. The scroll view is acting only as a control.

Set the content size of the scroll view based on how many "pages" there will be (i.e. the screen height multiplied by the number of images).

In the scroll view delegate method `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:` get the current offset of the scroll view.

You can use this offset to calculate the `topImage` and `bottomImage` (i.e. which index they will be from the `NSArray`).

Then change the position of the top `UIIMageView` based on the offset again.

**Rough code**

```
// create a topImageView and bottomImageView.
// set contentMode UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
// set clipsToBounds = YES
// place them both on self.view (bottom first)
// create a scrollView with a clear background.
// place it on the self.view.
// get the array of images.
// set the scrollView.contentSize = number of images * height of scrollView.

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat percentageOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y / CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.frame);

    NSInteger topPage = floorf(percentageOffset);
    CGFloat topPageOffset = percentageOffset - topPage;

    // make sure that you're not going outside of the index bounds first!!!!

    self.topImageView.image = self.images[topPage];
    self.bottomImageView.image = self.images[topPage + 1];

    // move the top image view so it looks like you are scrolling it.
    self.topImageView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds, -self.view.bounds.height * topPageOffset, 0);
}
```

This will give the impression that you are sliding the top image up out of the way and revealing the bottom image. It will also work continuously so if you "flick" the scroll view it will reveal one after the other until the scrollview slow and stops.

This is how I'd approach it I think.

Comment: I'm going to give this a go and will let you know how it goes! Thanks again!